# What is the difference between NOT(x > y) and (x < y) in an SQL query?

Tags: sql

What is the difference between the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee  WHERE NOT(start_date > '01-JAN-1970');
```

and this query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee  WHERE start_date < '01-JAN-1970';
```

Is there any difference, and if so, how is `NOT(x > y)` used differently from `(x < y)`. Can anyone provide an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Given the confusion it clearly sows, I'd say it's bad practice

Answer (score 8):

In `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE not(start_date > '01-JAN-1970')
```

will not use an `INDEX` on `start_date` if any, their optimizers are not smart enough.

Otherwise, if you correct the condition not be not strict in exaсtly one of cases (either `not(start_date >= '01-JAN-1970')` or `start_date <= '01-JAN-1970'`), the queries are equal.

Answer (score 5):

The non-NOT equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE not(start_date > '01-JAN-1970');
```

is

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE start_date <= '01-JAN-1970';
```

not

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE start_date < '01-JAN-1970';
```

since that would miss the case where start_date = '01-JAN-1970'

Answer (score 2):

Other than the obvious `not(start_date > '01-JAN-1970')` would *include* Jan 1, 1970 whereas `start_date < '01-JAN-1970'` would *exclude* it, I would think that these statements are identical.

Comment: Well, I was just going by the logic. If we were dealing with integers, the only difference between "not( i > 5 )" and "(i < 5)" is that the first case includes i=5 while the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

NOT() is simply a negation of whatever is inside the parentheses. In your example:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE not(start_date > '01-JAN-1970');
```

This would match employees whose start date is before 1970. Yes, you can reverse the <> bracket to negate it in this case, but in a more complex case or with other operators NOT is the only way to flip it.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the two clauses are pretty much equivalent - but if you want them to return exactly the same results then you should be using `<` and `>=` (or `<=` and `>`) rather than both `<` and `>`.

`NOT` becomes much more useful when you have set-based clauses. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_column NOT IN (273, 430, 9567, 8, 433, 765, 6252, 13)

SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_column NOT IN (SELECT another_column FROM another_table)
```

Without using `NOT` these queries would become at best cumbersome, or at worst impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the anything SQL-specific here, but from a logic point of view, the negation of < is >= (likewise, the negation of > is <=), so (x > y) and !(x < y) are not equivalent.

This is plain to see when you use a simple example like "What is not less than Y?". The answer being "Y and everything above it";

!(x < y) == (x >= y)

Answer (score 1):

not start_date > '01-JAN-1970' implies the start date can be equal to '01-JAN-1970'
start_date < '01-JAN-1970' means employees with '01-JAN-1970' for a start date is not selected

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting about rows where start_date == '01-JAN-1970' ;-)

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE start_date <= '01-JAN-1970';
```